# swift navigation bar title image position

Tags: swift, image, position, uinavigationbar, title

I created a navigation bar title image, it is working well.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 10))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    let image = UIImage(named: imageTitle)
    imageView.image = image

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

[image]

but i added an item button at the right side of navigation bar, the title image move to left a bit. How to make the image title in the center of the screen?

[image]

Comment: How you assign title text?

Comment: @JD. it is an image, no text at all

Comment: How you add bar button?

Comment: @JD. I add an bar button by using drag and drop in storyboard